# Gain access to selective subdirectories inside main directory

Tags: shell-script, command-line, permissions

I am looking for a way to gain access to only certain subdirectories inside the main directory in z/OS UNIX. Is there any way to accomplish this? Currently the main directory permissions are set to 700, So, I am unable to access any child directories inside the main directory. But setting 777 access on main directory will allow access to all users to all child directories inside the main directory. But my project requires access to only one sub directory inside the main directory. Is there any way or solution in z/OS UNIX to achieve this requirement?

Comment: If the permissions are `700` and you cannot access the contents, that must mean you're not the owner. `700` means `rwx------`: readable, writable and searchable to the owner.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the top-level directory permissions `777`, it will mean that all users can create and delete objects in that directory. You probably don't want that. Only `755`: `rwxr-xr-x`. Writable to owner, readable and searchable to others. Next, the individual child directory permissions control access. If you make all of the child directories `700` except for the one that is accessible to the team, that will work. Make that one `755`, if you want everyone to be able read and search the directory, but not create or delete files and subdirectories in it. Then individual file permissions in the directory determine who can access what file content.

Comment: But is it possible to retain 700 access on the main directory and then give access to the users to selective sub directory? Is there any option for this? My Project requires only the owner Id should access its root. But other users should be able to selectively access the sub directories.

Comment: @BrindhaSharadh I believe not. `700` means the main directory is not readable to them. So they cannot traverse that path component to get to the children. I **think** if you retain the `x` permission on it, but  not the `r` permission, that should work: `711`.  `x` for directories means "search".  The user cannot read the directory from beginning to end, but can look up a name in it, like when traversing a path component.

Comment: @BrindhaSharadha If you give people the `x` permission to a directory, they can access objects in it if they know (or can guess) their names. It's only a useful security mechanism if you have hard-to-guess names in there, similar to secure passwords.

Comment: Note that the permissions on the parent directory only govern access to the directory, not to the content. If the directory is `755` and you have a file in there which is `700`,  users can scan the directory to learn that the file exists and what it's name is, but they can't read or write the content. If you have `711` on the directory, they can learn that the file exists if they guess its name, but still cannot read the file.  If the name and existence of a file in the top directory being secret isn't important, that may be a good enough solution.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of permissions `0700` for a directory are that the user/owner has  read, write, execute/search access, but group and others have no access. Period. If you are not the owner and you want access to a directory inside this top-level directory you need a minimum of execute/search permission. Subdirectories and files inside this parent directory have their own permissions so you can be given access to one directory (and perhaps its contents) without being able to see anything other than names of other files and directories.

Consider:

```
umask 0022
mkdir -m700 parent parent/child1 parent/child2
touch parent/file1 parent/child1/file11 parent/child2/file21
tree

.
└── parent            # rwx------
    ├── child1        # rwx------
    │   └── file11    # rw-r--r--
    ├── child2        # rwx------
    │   └── file21    # rw-r--r--
    └── file1         # rw-r--r--
```

If you are the owner of `parent` and `child1`, `child2` then you will have full access to everything, otherwise you will have no access to anything.

```
chmod go+rx parent    # Add read,execute/search permission
```

This will give group and others access to the `parent` directory, but no permission to add or remove files/directories from it. As a result such people will be able to see `file1` and both directories `child1`, `child2`. Everyone will now be able to read the file `file1` by virtue of its permissions but only the owner will be able to modify it. Everyone will be able to see the directory names `child1` and `child2`, but only the owner will be able even to list their contents.

There is nothing stopping the owner of `parent` making you the only other member of a new group, and giving you group rights to the necessary `parent` and `child1` directories so that you can access them. You still won't have access to the other `child2` directory, and by restricting the permissions on `file1` it could be arranged that you had no access to that file either.

Answer (score 0):

First, permission 700 completely prevents other users from accessing anything in the directory, including its children. If you want to achieve this (which you shouldn't) you're going to have to do it in a roundabout way.

You didn't mention which filesystem you are using but I got it to work on a btrfs filesystem, other filesystems also support similar features.

I started from a folder A containing only the private stuff

Here are the steps I then took:

1. Create a subvolume for the shared stuff: `btrfs subvolume create /.../A/B`
2. Populate the subvolume: `touch A/B/private`
3. Create a new folder C to be accessed by users: `mkdir C`
4. mount A/B on C: `mount -o subvol=../A/B /dev/sdXX C` where `/dev/sdXX` is the path to the block device where your fs volume resides
5. Set the permissions of A: `chmod 700 A`
6. Set the permissions of A/B: `chmod 777 A/B`

The new layout is :

```
.
├── A
│   ├── B
│   │   └── public
│   └── private
└── C
    └── public
```

And any user can access A/B through C, but nobody other than the owner of A can access it in any way

Comment: While it achieves the goal it is not the roight way to fox the problem. If there is an issue with permissions you should fix the permissions not use a convoluted, non-portable workaround.

Comment: OP wants a root folder with 700 permission, you can't possibly achieve that with simple standard permissions. I'm simply answering the question taking into account exactly what OP wants. Also, this is not practical for users to have to access the files via a long path that doesn't give them access to anything else, the different mountpoint is a plus

Comment: Edited to make it clear that it's not something you're supposed to do in the first place, while still answering the question because it never hurts

Comment: Hi, I am using USS system , trying to upload a file to a path into a particular sub directory inside the main directory. But main directory is set to 700, and we are not supposed to change it from 700.. If you have any solution for USS system, then do let me know. I will explore the other answers also given here. Thanks everyone again for all the help.

Comment: The fact that you're using zOS (USS) is a HUGE information that you should add in your question. ZFS supports datasets which may be used in a similar way to btrfs subvolumes. You may create one with `zfs create pool_name/dataset_name`. Then I think you can mount it somewhere else like `mount -t zfs pool_name/dataset_name /mountpoint/path`. Note that I'm not familiar with zOS and that I thus could very well be saying bullcrap.